# JSON_EXTRACT on array of objects in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, json-extract

How to search in array of objects in mysql using JSON_EXTRACT ?

Here is the data json

```
[
  {
    "prd_type": "stand_alone",
    "prd_unitprice": 70
  },
  {
  
    "prd_type": "stand_alone",
    "prd_unitprice": 50,
  }
]
```

and here is my query, this query works if there is only one object in array, it ignores second object in search

```
 SELECT  id,order_detail
     FROM member_transactions WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(order_detail, "$[*].prd_unitprice") < JSON_ARRAY(60);
```

the above query will not fetch record from second object of array

Comment: Checkin in late; Can you explain what's  your issue since I get two records using this sample https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cU9zdYErhfA9UVGwSiTErd/0

Comment: Apparently its only checking for the 1st object in the list of object.
Even though the second object value satisfy the condition
Any help would be appreciated on the same